# Saving a map from a new print layout pane in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, maps, graphics

I have created a map with different layers, labels, scale bars, a north arrow, a legend, an overview pane, and other modifications. It took a long time to produce this map within the **'New Print Layout'** pane in the submenu, projects in QGIS. This image is going to be used in a peer-review paper and I may need to make future modifications at a later date.

I can't figure out how to save the **New Print Layout** window pane, so I come back at a future date and continue to work on it.

I have looked for a solution online and I can only find options to export the map into a different format i.e *.tiff*, *.pdf*, or *.png*.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open a New Prin Layout, you have to give it a name - let's suppose you name it `Layout_1`. When you save the project, the layout is automatically saved, too.

If you close and restart QGIS, you can open the layout going to `Menu Projects > Layouts` and select the layout you want to work with.

[image]

Comment: You may also drag&drop saved templates directly onto the map window in order to add them to your project.

Comment: Many thanks Babel, this post was really helpful